# But what's the *actual* way to *actually* solve a second order linear PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OL1WUyw2ag

Nope, that doesn't give me an explicit solution from boundary conditions, something's not right here.

This wouldn't even work on a first order problem, it would leave this weird unknown summed function left over even though the method of characteristics could easily give me an explicit solution from known boundary conditions.

I know this method in the video is related to an old and mostly useless calculus 3 trick to integrate that way if you happen to have some other piece of information about the function, but this is an ill-posed problem as far as I can tell. If solving PDE was as easy as integrating, well then the field of differential equations wouldn't even exist, you could solve $x'(t) = x(t)$ by just saying the solution is $\int x'(t)dt+C$ which obviously solves nothing.

Comment: Of course it doesn't give you anything having to do with boundary conditions, because none were provided in the problem!

Comment: That's the problem! It's ill-posed! Try this on just a regular ODE $x' = x.$ Even if you had a boundary condition there, what could you even do with this frivolous integral method? It's still stuck as some unknown integral. At best maybe you could use Picard's method infinitely many times to derive an analytic solution. This is one of the more useless video's I've encountered.

Comment: It's not ill posed. Recall that these are **partial**, not total, derivatives. That's why the solution looks different to the once you might get from a similar ODE.

Comment: But the solution isn't that different, it's just stuck as some unknown function that wasn't given by any condition. There is nothing about this technique that answers any questions unfortunately.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP cannot understand their own question.

Comment: I understand the question perfectly well and you're condescension is extremely toxic to a learning environment. Literally several people have verified my claim, that no boundary conditions were given, so you are the only one here who does not understand.

Comment: Why do you think boundary conditions are needed? When solving ordinary differential equations, do we always need to specify initial or boundary conditions? Many results in partial differential equations are given without any boundary conditions, e.g, the classical solution of the wave equation - 
$$u(x,t)=f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)$$

Comment: They're needed to be useful in any remote capacity.

Answer (score 1):

The reason no condition is given is because no condition is needed. Consider the simple ODE
$$\mathrm{D}^2_x[f](x)=0$$
Which of course has solution
$$f(x)=c_1 x+c_2$$
Since we imposed no boundary conditions on $f$, the constants are arbitrary. They can be any real or complex numbers we want.

Now consider the analogous PDE:
$$\partial^2_x [F](x,y)=0$$
The solution is exactly the same, but now instead of arbitrary *constants*, we have arbitrary *functions* -
$$F(x,y)=f_1(y)x+f_2(y)$$
Once again, since we imposed *no boundary conditions*, the functions are completely arbitrary. What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: What is wrong is that the functions are arbitrary. If I were to ask this of a professor they would say it is an ill-posed problem.

Comment: What is wrong with that? Plug in any functions you like for $f_1$ and $f_2$ and check whether it solves the PDE. It always will. Furthermore, every function that solves this PDE is of this form. Perhaps if you provide a definition of "ill-posed" we can discuss whether or not this problem is ill-posed. Which it is not.